# Does every sequence that satifies this requirement converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't $d(x_n,x_{n+1})\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ imply ${x_n}$ is Cauchy?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107336/why-doesnt-dx-n-x-n1-rightarrow-0-as-n-rightarrow-infty-imply-x-n)

If we have a sequence $(x_n)_n$ that satisfies this rule:

$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists n_0 : \forall n > n_0 : |x_{n+1} - x_n| < \epsilon$

Does is always converge?  The criterion is less strict than that of a Cauchy sequence, but I fail to find an example of a sequence which doesn't converge.

Comment: Revise your way to write 


$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists n_0 : \forall n > n_0 : |x_{n+1} - x_n| < \epsilon$. 

Where is the second 'such that' should be a 'implies' .  I would write                                             $\forall \epsilon>0\;\;\exists n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}:(n>n_{0})\Rightarrow |x_{n+1}-x_{n}|<\epsilon$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about $s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1 i$ ?

Answer (score 5):

Take $x_n=\sqrt n$. Then $$|x_{n+1}-x_n|=(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}=\frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}\le \frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}}$$
so the rule is satisfied (show it with $\varepsilon$). But the sequence doesn't converge (in $\mathbb R$).