# Is there a divergent sequence such that $(x_{k+1}-x_k)\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there a divergent sequence such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(x_{k+1}-x_k)=0$?

Comment: Take the partial sums  of the Harmonic series.

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107336/why-doesnt-dx-n-x-n1-rightarrow-0-as-n-rightarrow-infty-imply-x-n?lq=1) and its "linked" section (on the right side of the page) also.

Comment: This question is equivalent to asking whether there exist diverging series whose general term tend to $0$. Such sequences and such series are in bijection.

Comment: @Jonas Yup, just realized that as you posted your comment.

Comment: @Minimus: That is what julien's comment says, 8 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be any function such that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$.  Then $(f(1),f(2),f(3),\ldots)$ is an example.  In particular, you could take $f(x)=\log(x)$ or $f(x)=\sqrt x$.

Answer (score 3):

We know that $1/k \to 0$ so pick $x_k$ such that $x_{k+1} - x_{k} = 1/k$.

So start with $x_1 = 0$ and then define $x_{k+1} = 1/k + x_{k}$ now you can see this diverges since $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty 1/k$ does.

Answer (score 1):

Define $x_k:=\log k\ (k \ge 1)$, and then $x_{k+1}-x_k=\log(1+\frac{1}{k})\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$

Comment: If only...and only if...it had not already been mentioned in the comments and in another answer.

Comment: @julien Sorry about that, and I found it's equivalent to the first one as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n} \sim \log n$

Comment: No problem, I was only joking to quote your profile.

Comment: @Coiacy: In any case, you describe a different way to see that it is an example.  Regarding the last part of your comment, this property is not preserved under asymptotic equivalence. For example $\log n +(-1)^n\sim\log(n)$.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer Yeah, I agree and thanks. Actually you provide a more general answer. Well, next time before I post an answer, I'd better look at the posted answers carefully.