# cauchy sequence and necessary and sufficient condition for convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

**Question:** Show that for a sequence $\{x_m\}$ of real numbers to be a Cauchy sequence, it is necessary, but not sufficient that $|x_{m+1}-x_m|$ converges to zero.

**This is how I proved that it is necessary:**
for $\{x_m\}$ to be cauchy, for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists $n_o \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_a-x_b| \lt \epsilon$ for all $a,b \ge n_o$.
Now we can choose $a=m+1$ & $b=m$ such that both $a,b \ge n_o$. and by increasing or decreasing $m$ we can always  ensure that for all $\epsilon$,  $|x_{m+1}-x_m| \lt \epsilon $.
Is this proof correct?

How to prove that it is not sufficient condition?

Comment: I know this question is very simple but even then please guide me if I am going in the right direction.

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107336/why-doesnt-dx-n-x-n1-rightarrow-0-as-n-rightarrow-infty-imply-x-n/107344) for examples showing the condition is not sufficient.

Comment: It means the way I have proved necessary condition is also wrong?

Comment: No, your proof of necessary is right. As for not sufficient, you need to give an example of a sequence which satisfies the condition, but does not satisfy the condition of being Cauchy. David's link provides good examples.

Comment: The right idea seems to be there, but your phrasing could be better.  Say: "Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $N$ so that $|x_a-x_b|<\epsilon$ for all $a,b>N$.  Then in particular, for $m>N$, $|x_{m+1}-x_m|<\epsilon$. So..."

Comment: Yeah I read those. They are awesome. Infact Nick is very right when he says "The "for all" quantifier on m and n is what confuses people about Cauchy sequences."

Comment: thanx @DavidMitra