# Proving convergent sequence theorem.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

When $n$ approach to infinity prove that if

$$ \lim(a_{n+1}-a_n))= 0,$$ then $a_n$ is convergent.

I can prove the converse of this theorem is true but I can't prove this one. I know that since

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n))= 0, $$ we got for all $ε>0$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $|a_{n+1} -a_n| <ε$.

I also know that $|a_{n+1} -a_n| ≥ |a_{n+1}|-|a_n|$ that means $|a_{n+1}|-|a_n|<ε$. Now I don't know what to do next.

Comment: If $a_n=\sum_1^n1/k$, then $\lim(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$, but $a_n$ is not convergent.

Comment: @lab, what about $a_n=1/n$? It's convergent.

Comment: @lab, the $n$th term of *which* sequence?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107336/why-doesnt-dx-n-x-n1-rightarrow-0-as-n-rightarrow-infty-imply-x-n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k.$$
Clearly, $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_{n}-a_{n-1}| = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n = 0$, yet
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=+\infty.$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson I apologise, must have missed your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Check this sequence

> $$ a_n = \ln(n). $$