# Given a sequence in R is it sufficient to prove limit d(xn,xn+1) is 0 to show that it is cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis

I saw a proof in a  fixed point theorem which showed that d(xn,xn+p) is 0 as n goes to infinity hence the sequence is cauchy.
using triangle inequality if 
d(xn,xn+p) less than equal to d(xn,xn+1)+d(xn+1,xn+2)+....+d(xn+p-1,xn+p)
And since each of these terms tend to 0 as n tends to infinity then that implies d(xn,xn+p) tends to 0 .Therefore,sequence is cauchy.

Am i missing a condition here?
[image]

Comment: What if $x_n=\frac11+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n$ ?

Comment: Given a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ in $\Bbb R$, is it sufficient to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ to show the series is convergent?

Comment: One thing: $p$ could be related to $n$, like $p = n^2$. Then the sum is actually an infinite sum, and clearly the existence of such sum cannot be solely determined by the assumption $d(x_n, x_{n+1}) \to 0$.

Comment: No. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107336/why-doesnt-dx-n-x-n1-rightarrow-0-as-n-rightarrow-infty-imply-x-n).

Comment: For an Euclidean metric d(xn,xn+1) = xn + 1 - xn = 1.