# Prove that $d(x_n,x_{n+1})→0$ $\iff$ $(x_n)$ ia a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $X\neq\varnothing$ and let $d:X\times X→\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that

1. $$d(x,y)=0 \iff x=y,$$
2. $$d(x,y)=d(y,x),$$
3. $$d(x,z)≤\max⁡\{d(x,y),d(z,y)\}.$$

Let us say that $d$ is a metric. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$. Prove that   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,x_{n+1})=0$$
if and only if $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

I proved that if $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence then $d(x_n,x_{n+1})\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, but I could not prove that if  $d(x_n,x_{n+1})\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ then $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. I know that it is not true for arbitrary spaces. I tried to prove that just for this special metric.

Comment: **1.** Just for the reference, a metric satisfying the property 3 (which is stronger than the triangle inequality) is called an [*ultrametric*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space). **2.** As a hint, note that if $m<n$, then verify that $$d(x_m,x_n)\leq\max\{d(x_m,x_{m+1}),d(x_{m+1},x_{m+2}),\ldots,d(x_{n-1},x_n)\}$$ holds. (You may invoke mathematical induction to prove this.)

Comment: thank you......

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does $d(x_n,x_{n+1})\rightarrow 0$ imply $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324129/when-does-dx-n-x-n1-rightarrow-0-imply-x-n-is-a-cauchy-sequence)

Comment: $\max⁡\{d(x,y),d(x,y)$ is $d(x, y)$, isn't it?

Comment: @user58697 you are right. it was a mistake. I edited that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. We wish to find $N$ such that $m, n > N$ implies $d(x_m, x_n) < \epsilon$.

We know we can find $N$ such that $n > N$ implies $d(x_n, x_{n+1}) < \epsilon$.

I claim this $N$ suffices. Indeed, if $m, n > N$ are arbitrary, WLOG $n > m$. Now
\begin{align}
d(x_n, x_m)  \leq & \max\{d(x_n, x_{n+1}),\ d(x_{n+1}, x_m)\} \\
\leq &  \max\{\epsilon,\ d(x_{n+1}, x_m)\} \\
\leq& \max\{\epsilon, \max\{d(x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}), d(x_{n+2}, x_m)\}\} \\
\leq& \cdots\\
\leq & \max\{\epsilon, \epsilon, \ldots, d(x_{m-1}, x_m)\} \\
\leq &\  \epsilon
\end{align}
as desired. (Note that I was sloppy about strict inequality; it doesn't matter because you can pick $N$ to make the distances less than $\epsilon/2$, or just track the strict inequalities more carefully.)

Comment: thank you very much