# Is it possible for $x_{n+1}-x_{n}$ to converge to $0$, but the limit of $x_n$ to not exist?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I was reading about subsequences today and I came across an example which said the if $x_{n+1}-x_{n}$ converges to $0$, it's possible for $x_n$ to not have a finite limit (for example if we take $x_n$ to be the harmonic series). But then I thought "is it possible for the limit of $x_n$ to **not exist at all**?" and I think the answer is no,because I couldn't find any examples, but I am not sure. Could you please tell me what your opinion is on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107336/why-doesnt-dx-n-x-n1-rightarrow-0-as-n-rightarrow-infty-imply-x-n).

Comment: @DavidMitra Isn't the limit for $lnn$ + infinity ?

Comment: Oh, I should have read more closely. The link above has a counter example.

Comment: $x_n = \cos(\log(n))$ will oscillate between $(-1,1)$ sloowwwllllllyyyyyyyyyy...

Comment: Any series that is conditionally convergent but not absolutely convergent, can be rearranged to a series that does not converge at all.  You could even get partial sums so that $\limsup=+\infty$ and $\liminf = -\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $$x_n=\sin(\sqrt{n})$$

By MVT,

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}(\sin(\sqrt{n+1})-\sin(\sqrt{n}))=0$$

but

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_n$$
does not exist.

OR

$$x_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}$$
as a sequence of rationnals.

it has no limit in $ \Bbb Q$.

Comment: A slightly easier way to get $ \lim_{n\to +\infty}(\sin(\sqrt{n+1})-\sin(\sqrt{n}))=0$ for those who have not seen the MVT is to use $\sin(a)-\sin(b) = 2\sin(\frac{1}{2}(a-b))\cos(\frac{1}{2}(a+b)) \in [- 2\sin(\frac{1}{2}(a-b)), 2\sin(\frac{1}{2}(a-b))] $

Comment: @oskarszarowicz Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$x_n-x_{n-1}=\frac{(-1)^{\lceil\log_2n\rceil}}n$$
This is in effect taking the harmonic $x_n=H_n$ example, which has $\infty$ as a limit, and "folding it" into infinitely many intervals where $x_n$ goes up and down alternately by at least $\frac12$ per interval:

- From $x_2$ to $x_4$, $\frac13+\frac14>\frac12$ is added
- From $x_4$ to $x_8$, $\frac15+\frac16+\frac17+\frac18>\frac12$ is *subtracted*, etc.

Thus $x_n$ cannot have a limit.

Comment: Waw, what a great counterexample .

Comment: Hmmm... I guess I have to think about this example a lot more. So as I understand you're not giving any specific $x_n$, right? (this might be a stupid question, sorry)

Comment: @Britanica It is implied.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes!

Not only you can find examples were the limit is not finite but is for example $\infty$. You can also have examples were a full interval is a set of limit points of the sequence.

Look at a sequence that will slide back and forth from $0$ to $1$ with steps decreasing to zero for example. Let's for example consider $\{x_n\}$ whose initial terms are
$$
\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{2}{4}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{2}{6}, \frac{3}{6}, \frac{4}{6}, \frac{5}{6}, \dots$$

Formal definition of $\{x_n\}$ is

$$
x_n=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} &\text{ for } n= 1\\
\frac{n}{k+2} - \frac{k(k+1)}{2(k+2)} &\text{ for } \frac{k(k+1)}{2} \lt n \le \frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}
\end{cases}$$

The values of the sequence $\{x_n\}$ are in $(0,1) \cap \mathbb Q$. Moreover, one can notice that $\{x_n\}$ takes each rational number of $(0,1)$ as value an infinite number of times. Indeed for $\frac{p}{q} \in (0,1)$ with $1 \le p \lt q$ and $m \ge 1$ we have $$
\frac{(mq-2)(mq-1)}{2} \lt \frac{(mq-2)(mq-1)}{2} + mp$$ and $$\begin{aligned}
\frac{(mq-2)(mq-1)}{2} + mp &\le \frac{(mq-2)(mq-1)}{2} + m(q-1)\\
&\le \frac{(mq-2)(mq-1)}{2} + mq-1\\
&= \frac{(mq-1)mq}{2}
\end{aligned}$$ Hence $$\begin{aligned}
r_{\frac{(mq-2)(mq-1)}{2} + mp} &= \frac{(mq-2)(mq-1)}{2mq} + \frac{mp}{mq} - \frac{(mq-2)(mq-1)}{2mq}\\
&= \frac{mp}{mq}\\
&= \frac{p}{q}
\end{aligned}$$ proving the desired result. As the rational numbers of the segment $(0,1)$ are dense in $[0,1]$, we can conclude that the set of limit points of $\{x_n\}$ is exactly the interval $[0,1]$.

See [here](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/limit-points-of-real-sequences/) for additional examples.

Comment: Hey, you're website is amazing!! thank you

Comment: @Britanica Thanks for your comment!